# Skip python "import" statements in exuberant ctags

Tags: python, vim, exuberant-ctags

if I have two files

file a.py:

```
class A():
    pass
```

file b.py:

```
from a import A
b = A()
```

When I use ctags and press Ctrl+] in vim, it redirects me to import statement, not to class definition. In this code all is ok:

file a.py:

```
class A():
    pass
```

file b.py:

```
from a import *
b = A()
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you how to fix this issue with ctags, but you could try using cscope, or pyscope as a replacement.  They integrate with vim nicely.

Comment: pycscope is quite nice, or seems that way. Nice. +1

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can add the following line to your ~/.ctags file.

> --python-kinds=-i

to have ctags skip indexing import statements. To see what else you can enable/disable:

> ctags --list-kinds=python

Comment: This works great! Unfortunately, just adding `--python-kinds=-i` to the command does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I use a mapping similar to the following which allows me to choose when there are multiple matches for a given tag:

```
nnoremap <C-]> :execute 'tj' expand('<cword>')<CR>zv
```

Also, check the man page for ctags, you might find there is a way to disable this type of tagging.

Comment: Isn't that what `g<C-]>` does?