# Getting Vim to be aware of ctag type annotations for python

Tags: python, vim, ctags

I use Vim+Ctags to write Python, and my problem is that Vim often jumps to the import for a tag, rather than the definition. This is a common issue, and has already been addressed in a few posts here.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670061/366336) shows how to remove the imports from the tags file. This works quite well, except that sometimes it is useful to have tags form the imports (e.g. when you want to list all places where a class/function has been imported).

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749621/366336) shows how to get to the definition without removing the imports from the tags file. This is basically what I've been doing so far (just remapped :tjump to a single keystroke). However, you still need to navigate the list of tags that comes up to find the definition entry.

It would be nice it if it were possible to just tell Vim to "got the the definition" with a single key chord (e.g. ). Exuberant Ctags annotates the tag entries with the type of entry (e.g. c for classes, i for imports). Does anyone know if there is a way to get Vim to utilize these annotations, so that I could say things like "go to the first tag that is not of type i"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way for Vim itself to do that inference business and jump to an import or a definition depending on some context: when searching for a tag in your `tags` file, Vim stops at the first match *whatever it is*. [A plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) may help but I'm not aware of such a thing.

Instead of `<C-]>` or `:tag foo`, you could use `g]` or `:ts foo` which shows you a list of matches (with kinds and a preview of the line of each match) instead of jumping to the first one. This way, *you* are able to tell Vim exactly where *you* want to go.

Comment: Yeah, I thought not. I've looked for a plugin to do this (and tried writing my own) a while back, but had no luck. Just thought I'd ask here in case someone smarter than me has found a way :)