# Skip java "import" statements from exuberant ctags

Tags: java, exuberant-ctags

I want to build ctags such that it doesn't index the symbols in the import statements.

I came across a similar post for Python - [Skip python "import" statements in exuberant ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609433/skip-python-import-statements-in-exuberant-ctags)

and was exploring

```
ctags --list-kinds=java
a  annotation declarations
c  classes
e  enum constants
f  fields
g  enum types
i  interfaces
l  local variables [off]
m  methods
p  packages
```

But I dont see anything for specifically for import statements.

I already tried adding `--java-kinds=-p` to my `~/.ctags` file but that doesnt seem to work. Would appreciate the help

Comment: How about moving ~/.ctags to ~/.ctags.d/foo.ctags ? I guess your ctags is not exuberant-ctags but universal-ctags.

Comment: You are right. I am using universal-ctags and moving the ctags file worked. Thanks